# How to configure Exchange 2013 shared mailbox with activesync?

Tags: exchange-2013, android, activesync, shared-mailbox

I want to add both personal and shared mailboxes Exchange 2013 to Android devices using ActiveSync protocol, **not IMAP**. Is it possibile?
How can I use the personal use to authenticate the shared mailbox?

Somewhere I found these informations:

- Account type: Exchange
- User: mypersonal@mydomain.com/shared@mydomain.com
- Password: mypersonalpassword
- Domain: mydomain.com

But did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

Shared mailboxes can only be configured through the Outlook Android IMAP via IMAP, and I have yet to get that working myself (perhaps it only works with Office 365 shared mailboxes?)

Microsoft has support for shared mailboxes on their roadmap for mobile Outlook apps for 2019.